# custom QWidget layout problems

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, qwidget

I'm pretty new to QT and I've made my first custom QWidget subclass...it all works well, until I try adding some labels to it. They all get squashed into the top corner.

Here is my code:

```
   ARView::ARView(QWidget *parent, const char *name) {
deviceLBL = new QLabel(this);
targetLBL = new QLabel(this);
deviceHeadingLBL = new QLabel(this);
targetHeadingLBL = new QLabel(this);
distanceLBL = new QLabel(this);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();

layout->addWidget(deviceLBL);
layout->addWidget(targetLBL);
layout->addWidget(deviceHeadingLBL);
layout->addWidget(targetHeadingLBL);
layout->addWidget(distanceLBL);

this->setLayout(layout);

this->setupLocationUpdates();
```

}

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Why aren't all of these labels being layed out in a grid?
Or, if they are - why isn't the grid using all my subclasse's available space?

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the name is deceiving, but a QVBoxLayout is not a grid layout.  It is a Vertical Box layout.  Which means it is supposed to layout your items from top to bottom in the order that you add them.

So what you want is actually a QGridLayout.  If you look at the documentation for this kind of layout you'll see the following functions:

```
void    addWidget ( QWidget * widget, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0 )
void    addWidget ( QWidget * widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0 )
```

These should allow you to put your widgets wherever you want in a grid.

So the code I have added below will put deviceLBL and targetLBL on the first line, deviceHeadingLBL, and targetHeadingLBL on the second line, and just for fun, distanceLBL on the third line but taking 2 columns worth of space.

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout ();

layout->addWidget(deviceLBL, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(targetLBL, 0, 1);
layout->addWidget(deviceHeadingLBL, 1, 0);
layout->addWidget(targetHeadingLBL, 1, 1);
layout->addWidget(distanceLBL, 2, 0, 1, 2);
```

Which should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you create your widgets you need to add them to grid layout.

See [addWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1) method of  QGridLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried this but the result is the same. (I've updated my original post to include the new code).

Comment: Use row and column values. You are not using them . layout->addWidget(deviceLBL,0,0); layout->addWidget(targetLBL,0,1); etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but the values are not row and column values. The first is a stretch value, and the second is an alignment value. What is the correct way to set rows and columns please?